# What is wrong with this apache2 configuration?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration

I want to set up apache2 so that the wordpress website is served via port 80 and some other php website served via port 8080. This is on my local machine running Ubuntu 15.10.

The sites-available/000-default.conf contains:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/php-website

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enter **localhost** into the browser, I get the Wordpress website. When I enter **localhost:8080**, I get (redirected it seems to) localhost.

What could be wrong here? I though there might be something wrong with the second VirtualHost config so it's defaulting to the first, so I changed their order. Same thing happened however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser issue. Chrome and Firefox were automatically changing the URL to localhost. It works with curl and in Incognito/Private modes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with wordpress configuration. I think wordpress uses wordpress adress (url) or site adress (url) to redirect if you are in another domain. So you should configure this adresses to localhost and localhost:8080.